# Python Error "Can't Encode Characters in Position..."

Tags: python-3.x

I am receiving an error on returning the line:

```
print(page)
```

within the block of code below:

```
import requests 

page = requests.get("https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/IC4WSA")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

The error returned is below:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 
22971-22979: character maps to <undefined>
```

Do I need python libraries with additional character objects to return the parsed html?  And if so how do I determine the object/character types necessary to return parsed html values?  I am not sure how to view the character values at position 22971-22979.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean ``print(soup)`` ?

Comment: You must be on Windows, right? Python attempts to convert the input (UTF8) to your (crummy!) console character set and it fails. That said ... `print(soup.text[22971:22979])` only shows spaces. Configure your console to accept UTF8 and try again.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that when Python tries to print to the console a string (printing a `BeautifulSoup` object prints its string representation), then the unicode string needs to be converted to bytes that the console can display.

Converting from unicode to bytes is known as *encoding* a string. There are several encodings that Python can use to do the conversion, UTF-8 is one of them, latin-1 another, cp1252 (cp = code page, a Windows concept) yet another. There are many of them, see the documentation.

You can check what encoding the Python interpreter will use like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'utf-8'
```

How Python determines what encoding to try to use depends on a few factors:

- If you're on Windows and use Python < 3.6, then the current windows console code page will be used. You can override the encoding by using the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`.
- If you're on Windows and use Python 3.6, then the utf-8 encoding will be used (unless you set some special environment variables to use the legacy windows encoding functionality).

From your error, I guess that you are running Python < 3.6 on Windows. The error means that the selected encoding is unable to represent one of the unicode characters from the HTTP response. Either change your console or override the encoding:

```
c:\> SET PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
c:\> python myscript.py
... you should not get an error, but the console will not be able to 
display all characters correctly
```

If you do:

```
c:\> python myscript.py > output.txt
```

I.e. redirect the output to a file, you can open the file in a text editor that understands utf-8 (for instance notepad++).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies...I overrode the encoding by adding .encode('utf-8') which printed in the console. also, interesting to learn of the .txt output approach.  Thanks again!